# Detect if NSString is a float number

Tags: ios

I am trying  to dectect if an NSString it's a float number, for exemple : @"-73.041382"

But when I try with this method I obtain a wrong result:

```
-(bool) isNumeric:(NSString*) checkText{

NSNumberFormatter* numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSNumber* number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:checkText];
if (number != nil) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

}

Someone have an idea!?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong result"?

Comment: I mean the method return false;

Comment: Might have something to do with the locale.

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Determine_if_a_string_is_numeric#Objective-C what about this?

Comment: @Etienne: yes it's that! thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
-(bool) isNumeric:(NSString*) checkText{
   return [[NSScanner scannerWithString:checkText] scanFloat:NULL];
}
```

i'm currently not on mac so i can't check it, hope it helps

Comment: Works for 1 or 1.2 or 1b but not b1

Comment: no, it does not mean it's a pure numeric. For exmaple, it could return true for @"3.111fffff"

Answer (score 10):

I have found the answer :

```
-(bool) isNumeric:(NSString*) checkText{

NSNumberFormatter* numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
//Set the locale to US
[numberFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];
//Set the number style to Scientific
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle];
NSNumber* number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:checkText];
if (number != nil) {
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This validates even numbers in format 9.0E-4 and invalidates 9.0E-4xxx. This is the only solution I found who does that. Thanks!